# Windows server "Disable recursive dns"

Tags: windows-server-2019, dns-server

I've disabled DNS recursion in my DNS server (Operating System: Windows server core 2019) using this method [Disable DNS recursion](https://support.appliedi.net/kb/how-to-disable-recursion-on-a-windows-dns-server/), Also I've executed this commands in my DNS server `PowerShell`

```
Set-DnsServerRecursion -Enable $False
Clear-DnsServerCache
```

But still when I run

```
nslookup 'some random domain' 'My dns server IP Address'
```

in my PC, It answers like this:

```
Non-authoritative answer:
Name: some domain name
Address: IP address
```

But actually it should be `*** UnKnown can't find some domain name: Query refused`

What's I'm doing wrong? Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone who stuck in this issue, At the end I've used DNS Policies to just allow my domain and block other domains requests.

```
Add-DnsServerQueryResolutionPolicy -Name "BlackholePolicy" -Action DENY -FQDN "NE,*.mydomain"
```

Also you can use IGNORE instead of DENY.